# Is it possible to exchange data between Android devices at distance without a server?

Tags: android, firebase, server, location, exchange-server

I'm trying to develop an app which is going to control a kid's location. The idea is:

1. I run the app on the kid's phone and then start service which is listening to an incoming SMS event.
2. The parent's phone sends SMS with code "where are you?"
3. Having got the right code from the right phone number, the kid's phone finds its location and sends the location data as a SMS back to the parent.
4. The parent's phone gets the location and shows it.

On such a condition all works well, but I'd like to send data using the net. The question is it possible to do such a task without a server? If server must be, then what will be the sipmliest way to execute that task? Should I use a chat server idea, Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically, you would need some sort of server to act as a middleman between the two. Firebase would be good, although I would not rely on Firebase Cloud Messaging for delivering the actual data (just notifying the other device that "new data" is available).

Personally I would approach it like this:

- Parents phone adds record to database (lets say Cloud Firestore) which says "Location has been requested for this user by this user".
- Server sends a Push notification to the child's device which wakes the app up.
- App checks server to see if there are any location requests in the database for the current user.
- It finds the location request and populates the coordinates.
- Another push notification is sent to the parents phone to wake the app up.
- It checks the database and can see the location request has been populated.

There are a few other steps and corners that could be cut, but that's how it would work in principal (and how it does work for a lot of applications).

Comment: Well, what's the best way to realize "the kid's app checks the server for a location"  request logic? Could I do that with a some of Firebase callback function?

Comment: And I'm still confused about a server. Could Firebase act like a server or I need to use another server in any case?

Comment: So some peoples first idea would be to have it "poll" the server on some sort of timer, checking if there's any new requests. That doesn't work so well with mobile applications though, because once the app isn't being used by the user, it's only allowed to perform a restricted amount of actions (because of battery life etc). So polling a sever every 5 minutes is out of the question. However, apps have the ability to be "woken up" by a push notification and are given a short amount of time to perform some action, for example, checking the server for any new requests.

Comment: Typically you would have a backend application that you built (or multiple applications) that would ultimately run on some physical servers somewhere, along with a database. Firebase effectively provides these as services, so you don't have to worry about running your own database etc.

Comment: Could you give me some links to examples where that idea (about using and setup backend app for exchaging data between devices) might be implemented?

Comment: Sure, so you could follow a tutorial for most whatapp-style apps (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android#0 for example.)

The main difference between a messaging app and your app is the data being sent (instead of populating a database of messages, you are populating the database with "location requests" and subsequent "location responses".

The other main difference is that your app needs some way of being "woken up" (e.g by a push notification) while most of the chat tutorials assume the user is going to have the device open constantly.